# Open new browser window

Tags: javascript

I am new to javascript and I am using the code below to open a browser window and do some things. However, when I open multiple files simultaneously, it just opens a new tab in the existing browser window, but I want it to open in a new window (preferably incognito mode if possible). Based on my research, I'm thinking I can just modify the `if` statement, but I'm not sure how.

```
<html>
   <body onload="window.setTimeout('document.getElementById(\'criimlaunch\').click();', 1000);">

      <script>
         var macroCode = '';
         macroCode += 'PROMPT HELLO!\n';

         function launchMacro()
            {
            try
               {
                  if(!/^(?:chrome|https?|file)/.test(location))
                  {
                     alert('iMacros: Open webpage to run a macro.');
                     return;
                  }

                  var macro = {}; 
                  macro.source = macroCode;
                  macro.name = 'EmbeddedMacro';

                  var evt = document.createEvent('CustomEvent');
                  evt.initCustomEvent('iMacrosRunMacro', true, true, macro);
                  window.dispatchEvent(evt);
               }
            catch(e)
            {
               alert('iMacros Bookmarklet error: '+e.toString());
            };
         }
      </script>

      <a id="criimlaunch" href="javascript:launchMacro();">Launch iMacros</a>

   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: None of that code creates a new window or tab.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Open a URL in a new tab (and not a new window) using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-a-url-in-a-new-tab-and-not-a-new-window-using-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to open new window you should use

```
window.open (URL, windowName[, windowFeatures])
```

I think below links will help you.

[Using the window.open method](http://javascript-coder.com/window-popup/javascript-window-open.phtml)

[window.open w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Chrome extensions with the tabs permission can use the chrome.windows.create method:

```
chrome.windows.create({"url": url, "incognito": true});
```

However, to access it, you'll either need to write your own extension or find an existing one which provides a suitable hook

Answer (score -1):

You can try

```
windows.create({"url": url, "incognito": true});
```